# css list items fill up div

Tags: html, css

i have html code

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  ...
  <li></li>
  </ul>
```

How to create template list as picture

```
i.stack.imgur.com/9jTbC.jpg
```

Any idea, Thanks

Comment: Please put your code in the question itself to help prevent link rot.

Comment: Please ask a clear and details question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're trying to achieve masonry template look. This is might be helpful for you: http://masonry.desandro.com/